# Problems with AppCompat 21 Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-theme, android-appcompat, material-design

So I changed from using Material theme to AppCompat to support non Lollipop devices, and I encountered a couple of problems using the AppCompat toolbar.
First of all, the toolbar is not using the primary color:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Primary color is set to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base"/>

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I am using this theme for my activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
 </activity>
```

I am adding the toolbar to the Activity like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The Activity is extending `ActionBarActivity`

Also I noticed all the content is shifted up a bit when using the AppCompat library. Is this intentional? The menu button is displaying black, even though I chose the light theme. And the toolbar is not showing any shadow below itself, like a vanilla material one would. How can I fix those errors?

Comment: remove `android:` from everything when using appcompat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.create theme

```html
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

     <style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

2.set it to activity

`<activity
            android:name="OtherApp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
        </activity>`

3. create toolbar

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

4. and finally

`toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

here is my result 
[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I change the theme of the toolbar to be white? I don't want the menu to look black. And any fix for the content in the activity being shifted up?

Comment: add in your toolbar   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"   may be help to make menu white

Comment: and please tell me from above image that content shifted up ? because i think it's in vertically centered.

Comment: I don't mean the action bar, I mean the content below the action bar, like textViews. Using the material action bar they were at a certain position, and after using the appcompat action bar they are shifted up like 50dp

Answer (score 1):

While using appcompact library you should not use like this `android:colorPrimary`, it should be `colorPrimary`
It seems you have problem in your style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base"/>

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Change it to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base"/>

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I already figured that out, but thanks ayway. Do you have a fix about the content being shifted up?

Comment: I know that, but how can I fix that?